# Python Try-except doesn't output what expected

Tags: python-3.x, exception

```
print("Give me two numbers, I'll sum them")
print("Enter 'q' to quit")


while True:
  num1 = input("Please, enter a number here: ")
  if num1 == 'q':
    break
  num2 = input("Please, enter a number here: ")
  if num2 == 'q':
    break
    
  try:
    sum = int(num1) + int(num2)
  except ValueError:
    print("'q' entered, program exit 0")
  else:
    print(sum)
```

Hi the above program in Python3 works fine when numbers are inputted.
But when I input q, it just exits with no exception.
May you please assist me with this issue?
Thank you very much indeed.

Answer (score 1):

the `break` statement will exit your loop without printing anything, because your `try-except` test is after breaks.

Here is what you can do:

```py
print("Give me two numbers, I'll sum them")
print("Enter 'q' to quit")


while True:
  num1 = input("Please, enter a number here: ")
  if num1 == 'q':
    print("'q' entered, program exit 0")
    break
  num2 = input("Please, enter a number here: ")
  if num2 == 'q':
    print("'q' entered, program exit 0")
    break

  if not num1.isdecimal() or not num2.isdecimal():
    print('Wrong input, please enter decimal numbers !')
    continue
    
  sum = int(num1) + int(num2)
  print(sum)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's understandable. Even though I've seen a similar program running ok with try-except-else inside the 'while' loop. Anyway, I'll take stock of your comment.

Comment: You can use a try-except if you want, but in my opinion that's not the best choice as in some programs you can have edge cases that you want to be raise by exceptions :)